# Testing socket activation failed, Django and Gunicorn

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

when I try to do this:

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

It answers with this:

```
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Wed 2019-09-25 04:23:44 UTC; 3min 27s ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Sep 25 04:23:44 myproject systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
root@myproject :/myprojectdir# sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-25 04:27:02 UTC; 13s ago
 Main PID: 25219 (code=exited, status=3)

Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]:   File "/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]:   File "/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]:     __import__(module)
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]: [2019-09-25 04:27:02 +0000] [25245] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25245)
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]: [2019-09-25 04:27:02 +0000] [25219] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject gunicorn[25219]: [2019-09-25 04:27:02 +0000] [25219] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Sep 25 04:27:02 myproject systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It seems it's trying to find a myproject.wsgi, but I never created one and the tutorial which I followed had no mention of it too.
However, it's supposed to answer this:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm sorry if I'm not showing anything helpful, but I don't know what more I could show. I'm using: Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04 in Google Cloud.

Comment: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hybroo'". Is that your app name?

Comment: Try adding this pluging `sudo apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3` to help in finding the wsgi file. This also because we have some files/processes that are system-wide while others are in the `virtualenv` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django creates the Wsgi file by default when creating the project. It is present in the project directory with name wsgi.py.

You need to make changes to the systemctl service file so that it can find the wsgi file.

Edit

> /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

And add the following to the [Service] section

> WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/project